# How to send multi parmater email link using HostServices.showDocument?

Tags: java, email, javafx-8

I am trying to generate an email using:

```
String emailAddress = "someone@somewhere.com";
hostServices.showDocument("mailto:" +
emailAddress + 
"?Subject=This is my subject" + 
"&body=Please see the details at this link: "
+ "http://myserver.com:8080/application/page.html?param1=SOMETHING&param2=12345";
```

This creates the email correctly up to the second parameter and my email string looks like this:

Please see the details at this link: http://myserver.com:8080/application/page.html?param1=SOMETHING

Is there a way to escape that so I get the full URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that switching the "&" after the &body tag to %26 works and allows the full URL.